# What is the meaning of sweep off

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence what is the meaning of ***sweep off***

> > Plague **swept off** millions.

**kill** better describes the sentence, but no dictionary have the word **sweep off** meaning **to kill/be killed**.

In  [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sweep+off)  its meaning is **to escort or take away** but it doesn't suit the context.

Comment: Where did you get "Plague swept off millions"? Was that the complete sentence? Did you leave something out?

Comment: Actually in my grammar exercise there is a sentence in which I am to fill the correct form of the verb **sweep** though I filled in the correct form but didn't understand the meaning of the sentence

Comment: Did you copy the entire exercise, and is it an accurate copy? Also, please [edit] your post to include additional details or make other improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "escort or take away", in the figurative sense of "taking away someone's life". It is figurative as it gives an image of a sweeper who brushes away a lot of bits of dirt with a single stroke, similar to how plague *swept* through Asia and Europe in the 1300s.

Dictionaries don't list all the possible metaphorical meanings, as they keep changing and so have to be understood from the context.